# Solidity: How are multiple return values returned?

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha

Working in truffle with TDD testing and am getting some errors when evaluating the return values of some functions.

If a function is returning multiple values in Solidity, how are they presented? Is it in an array or an object?

```
    it('can put the star on sale if ownership passes', async function() {
        await this.contract.putOnSale(1,50000, {from: accounts[0]});
        assert.equal(await this.contract.isOnSale(1), {true, 50000});
    });
```

Errors I am getting are as such:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (0, 1, ...) } to equal { Object (identifier, code, ...) }
  + expected - actual

   {
  -  "0": "Barcode"
  -  "1": "1234567890-abcde"
  -  "2": "This is asset #1. There is not much to say about this asset given that it is fictional."
     "code": "1234567890-abcde"
     "description": "This is asset #1. There is not much to say about this asset given that it is fictional."
     "identifier": "Barcode"
   }
```

Thanks in advance and take care.

Comment: Um.. It literally tells you what is expected and what is actually returned in the error..

Comment: Hey @ThomasClowes. I am aware that truffle tells me it is expecting an object but for some reason setting the expected return variables in an object does not seem to work. So I was wondering if something might be going wrong and I (and Mocha test) shouldn't expect an object. Hence, the question. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
assert.equal(await this.contract.isOnSale(1), {true, 50000});
```

To this:

```
var [x, y] = await this.contract.isOnSale(1);
assert(x === true && y.equals(50000));
```